# What is the difference between Strong, Weak Force and Electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, weak-interaction, strong-force

I was watching a documentary and they said that the Strong Force is what keeps the nucleus together (Nuclear Force) and Electromagnetism is what causes the attraction between electron and nucleus so that they don't fall apart. I mean what? What's the difference?

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd link](https://xkcd.com/1489/)

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to know, and what exactly you find lacking about standard resources such as the corresponding Wikipedia articles.

Comment: @M.Enns That explained a lot. Now I know that me being confused about weak force makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

An electron has a negative electrical charge, and a proton has positive electrical charge. Opposite charges attract, and so the electrons are held in to the nucleus (remember the nucleus is made up of protons and neutrons). Now, same charges repel, and if the nucleus is filled with protons, they'll repel each other, right? So there has to be another force to overcome the electromagnetic force within the nucleus and hold the nucleus together. The strong force only works over very small distances, so it doesn't do anything with the electrons, and the bigger the atom, the more unstable it gets (after iron, anyway) and that's because the strong force starts have trouble holding in all the protons. So electromagnetism holds the electrons in, and the strong force holds the nucleus together. (The electrons don't spiral in because of the Pauli Exclusion Principle.)

As for the weak force, that's what causes radioactivity. The weak force is also only "useful" over very short distances, and it's several orders of magnitude weaker than electromagnetism or the strong force, though its much, much stronger than gravity. The weak interaction (in a nutshell) helps quarks swap their flavors (quarks come in six flavors, up, down, strange, charm, top, and bottom) which then causes a decay. For example,  during beta minus decay, a down quark within a neutron is changed into an up quark, converting the neutron to a proton and resulting in the emission of an electron and an electron antineutrino.

Hope this helps!

You can learn more about the weak force [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction). You can learn more about the electromagnetic force [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism). You can learn more about the strong force [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction).